# OpenGL / GLSL - Uniform block data values incorrect

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

My shader has a uniform block as such:

```
layout (std140) uniform LightSourceBlock
{
    vec3 test;
    vec3 color;
} LightSources;
```

The data for this block is supposed to come from a buffer object which is created like so:

```
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1,&buffer);

GLfloat data[6] = {
    0,0,0,
    0,0,1
};
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,buffer);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,sizeof(data),&data[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

The buffer is linked to the uniform block before rendering:

```
unsigned int locLightSourceBlock = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program,"LightSourceBlock");
glUniformBlockBinding(program,locLightSourceBlock,8);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,8,buffer);
```

From my understanding this should be setting 'color' inside the block in the shader to (0,0,1), but the value I'm getting instead is (0,1,0).

If I remove the 'test' variable from the block and only bind the three floats (0,0,1) to the shader, it works as intended.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did specify `layout (std140)` for your UBO, you must obey the alginment rules defined there. That layout was first specified (in core) in the [OpenGL 3.2 core spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.pdf), section 2.11.4 "Uniform Variables" in subsection "Standard Uniform Block Layout":

> 1. If the member is a scalar consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is N.
> 2. If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N,
>      respectively.
> 3. If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 4N.
> 4. If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array
>      element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up to the
>      base alignment of a vec4. The array may have padding at the end; the
>      base offset of the member following the array is rounded up to the
>      next multiple of the base alignment.
> 5. If the member is a column-major matrix with C columns and R rows, the matrix is stored identically to an array of C column vectors with
>      R components each, according to rule (4).
> 6. If the member is an array of S column-major matrices with C columns and R rows, the matrix is stored identically to a row of S  C column
>      vectors with R components each, according to rule (4).
> 7. If the member is a row-major matrix with C columns and R rows, the matrix is stored identically to an array of R row vectors with C
>      components each, according to rule (4).
> 8. If the member is an array of S row-major matrices with C columns and R rows, the matrix is stored identically to a row of S  R row
>      vectors with C components each, according to rule (4).
> 9. If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is N, where N is the largest base alignment value of any of its
>      members, and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4. The
>      individual members of this substructure are then assigned offsets by
>      applying this set of rules recursively, where the base offset of the
>      first member of the sub-structure is equal to the aligned offset of
>      the structure. The structure may have padding at the end; the base
>      offset of the member following the sub-structure is rounded up to the
>      next multiple of the base alignment of the structure.
> 10. If the member is an array of S structures, the S elements of the array are laid out in order, according to rule (9).

For your case, point 3 applies. So, you need to pad another float before the second vector begins.