# Uniform Buffer Object not aligned. GLSL access broken

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Using GLFW, GLEW (Although it shouldn't matter)

When passing a struct to the fragment shader, unexpected behavior is observed:
If I pass the ambient color directly:

```
out vec3 color
...
color = MaterialCols.ambient
```

Everything works as expected. When passing diffuse, it is offset by 1 (i.e. the green channel is red, the blue channel is green)

When passing specular, the first value is the green channel of the previous vec3 (diffuse).

I believe this is an issue of alignment. It seems either that GLSL only wants to access vec3 components on a specific alignment, or that the C++ code is adding some padding (for reasons unkown).

This is the data allocation. It is passed as a uniform buffer object. If required, I can add the code used.

#### C++:

```
typedef  struct  material_colors{
    glm::vec3 ambient;
    glm::vec3 diffuse;
    glm::vec3 specular;
}material_cols;
```

#### GLSL:

```
uniform MaterialColors {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
} MaterialCols;
```

Comment: UBOs have very clear alignment rules (when using one of the standard layouts, or the implementation might impose it's own rules if you don't). Have a look at [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807797/opengl-glsl-uniform-block-data-values-incorrect/20807965#20807965) for a similiar question.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. If I had found those rules earlier, I wouldn't have asked this pointless question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per derhass' comment, and the related section 2.11.4 titled "Uniform Variables"in the OpenGL 3.2 Core specifications:

> *3.* If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 4N.

So, by padding the c++ struct using a float after the first vec3, brings the diffuse into alignment.

C++

```
typedef  struct  material_colors{
    glm::vec3 ambient;
    float padding;
    glm::vec3 diffuse;
    glm::vec3 specular;
}material_cols;
```

Comment: Well, this is partially correct (`diffuse` is now aligned)... but if you intend to use `specular` that is misaligned as well. I would also suggest that you add `layout (std140)` to your Uniform Block declaration to guarantee this behavior. These rules apply to `std140` and that is ***not*** the default layout, by default Uniform Buffers are packed in an implementation-defined way and you are supposed to query the offsets. You could be getting lucky here and your implementation is choosing `std140` rules for its implementation-defined packing, but you cannot portably rely on this.

Comment: I have added layout (std140). This still means I have to pad right? It just ensures that the alignment required is *standard*, making it portable across platforms?