# Using opengl4, can I map `uniform` variables to my userspace memory?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, glsl, shader

(I asked the same question in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133399/can-i-map-uniform-variables with no answer so far).

I'm literally just starting with GLSL, I'm using python and I actually can't run 330 (intel hd3000 on Debian) so I'm using 130, so far is ok.

I started using `in` first and didn't know about `uniform` variables, I used a piece of code that allow me to map the in variable in the user space memory and then map this to a numpy array using ctypes.

In my loop I call:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
```

After that I map the variables associated with the vertices back to my user space:

```
def map_buffer(size):
    func = ctypes.pythonapi.PyBuffer_FromReadWriteMemory
    func.restype = ctypes.py_object
    p = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE)
    buffer = func(ctypes.c_void_p(p), size)
    array = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype='float32')
    return array
```

This code basically just use the pointer returned by `glMapBuffer` and creates an array with the buffer starting at that position.

I can manipulate that array with `numpy` without problems and then unmap it so the next loop would see the changes, so far are only vertices of a rotating triangle.

Now, my series of questions are simple:

1. it seems I should use `uniform` for this isn't?
2. If so, I can't see how to map an `uniform` variable, and I really love to use `numpy` for the manipulations, how can I map the memory of a uniform to my user space?
3. Is there any performance penalty on using `in` instead of `uniform`? (beside the natural overhead of mapping on python, since no memory is allocated in the process I guess is good enough).

From what I understand uniform are constant or immutable from the point of view of the shaders, so only outside the shaders can be modified. That's how I'm using the `in` variable so far. So, it seems natural to prefer `uniform` over `in`, but I prefer the API for `in` than for `uniform`, unless there is a performance issue I would continue using `in`.

Bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to address different parts of your question separately.

**"Mapping Uniforms"**

You can use GL buffer objects as a backend stoarge for uniform values. The concept is called [Uniform Buffer Object (UBO)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), and it is available since OpenGL 3.1.

The key idea is that you can your uniform variables in so called [interface blocks](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)) in the GLSL shader code, like this

```
layout(std140) uniform some_block_name {
    vec4 foo;
    float bar;
    mat4 baz;
}
```

Note that you can have different uniform blocks in a single shader, and each of these can source the data from different buffer object (which you have to bind on the CPU side).

If you don't specify any `layout`, the GL will lay out the data in the buffer as it sees fit, and you basically have to query the byte offset for each variable (just like you have to query the location for an ordinary uniform). However, using the `std(140)` layout as I did in the example will use some standardized alignment rules, so that you can calulate the offset for each member directly, without having to query it, and with the advantage that it will not be dependent on the GL implementation. The exact alignment rules can be found in the OpenGL spec, I also did reproduce them [in this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807797/opengl-glsl-uniform-block-data-values-incorrect/20807965#20807965).

**Uniforms versus Vertex Attributes**

> From what I understand uniform are constant or immutable from the point of view of the shaders, so only outside the shaders can be modified. That's how I'm using the `in` variable so far. So, it seems natural to prefer `uniform` over `in`.

You should think of this not in terms of some abstract pipeline stage, but centered on a single *shader invocation*.
The `in`puts of your vertex shader are the so-called vertex attributes. And these are values which do (or at least could) *vary per vertex*. Uniforms, on the other hand, stay *constant* during the whole draw call - this means that the vertex attributes are is the data which is different for each invocation, while the uniforms are shared between them all.

So how this is mean to be used is that you put all the vertex data into vertex attributes. And you put some extra parameters you need for the calculations, but which don't depend on the exact vertex, into uniforms.

> I can manipulate that array with numpy without problems and then unmap it so the next loop would see the changes, so far are only vertices of a rotating triangle.

It is not clear of what you are trying to achieve in the end, but what you are doing here is not how the render pipeline is supposed to be used.

The idea is that your model is constant, and only the transformation changes. So you upload it once into a buffer, and *let the GPU* re-transform everytime you draw it. Usually, we are using 4x4 matrices and linear algebra for that, so we simply update some uniform matrix for the draw call, and never re-specify the geometry (unless we actually want to morph it - on the CPU, which we usually don't want).

However, with the increasing flexibility of the programmable GPUs, the line between uniforms and vertex attributes begins to blur. Conceptually, you can now do something like

```
uniform vec3 vertexPosition[someBigNumber];
// ...
vec3 pos = vertexPosition[gl_VertexID]
gl_Position = some_matrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
```

That way, you can work around some limits of vertex attributes (i.e. there are 16 attribute slots with up to a vec4 each, only), but depending on the GPU, you might or might not pay some price in form of performance penalties due to the further layer of indirection. Some GPUs do have special hardware units which optimize fetching of the vertex attributes (allowing it to better schedule the vertex shader invocations). Also note the uniform memory itself are typically limited to only 2kB, UBOs to 64k. You could use ofther buffer object types for such usages, though (like [texture buffer objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) or [shader storage buffer objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)).

**Your actual questions**

> 1. it seems I should use uniform for this isn't?

Well, it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve, so I can't give any clear answer to that. In a normal case, the positions of the vertices is considered an vertex attribute, so you shouldn't use uniforms for that.

> 2. If so, I can't see how to map an uniform variable, and I really love to use numpy for the manipulations, how can I map the memory of a uniform to my user space?

You can use UBOs.

> 3. Is there any performance penalty on using in instead of uniform? (beside the natural overhead of mapping on python, since no memory is allocated in the process I guess is good enough).

That very much depends. On your actual use case and data access pattern. On the GPU. On your actual workload - i.e. the vertex shader might not be the bottleneck (it certainly isn't in the case of just drawing a single triangle per draw call), so even if there is some conceptual performance difference in the VS, there might be zero effect on the actual rendering performance.

I'd still say that using vertex attributes for per-vertex data *should* be at least as fast or faster as using uniforms, at least in normal use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm planning to do more that just rotating or translating my models, i.e. if I want to model a solid as it deforms under some force the vertices of the model will be transformed in such a way that a matrix multiplication is not enough, tI was thinking in map the variables to numpy arrays compute the changes according to any deformation and then map it back so the shader can see the changes. Should I do all that inside a shader then? Bye.

Comment: If you _can_ do it in the shaders, than you probably should. It all depends on how well your algorithm maps to the massive parallel single-instruction-multiple-data paradigm GPUs are providing nowadays. If, for example your deformation depends on a lot of neighboring vertices, doing it in a vertex shader might become complicated (and using some UBO or TBO for the vertex data so that you actually can access the neighbors begins to make sense). You might also consider using compute shaders for your deformations.